# How to make auto fill prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a javascript Input in which I would like for search suggestions to show below the input box based on what the user is searching for. I have a large database of countries using fetch API and I would like to have it so that when the user is typing his/her country in the input field, search suggestions for the country show up directly below it.
 Here's my code so far:

```js
let searchInput = document.getElementById("input")

searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let countries = data["Country"]
      console.log(data["Country"])
      const searchValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
      const suggestions = countries.filter(function(country) {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchValue)
      })


    });
  console.log(suggestions)
})
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Country Name">
```

From this code, I'm not getting what I'm looking for. I'm getting `undefined` every time I switch a key in the input field. What I want to do is to filter the results based on country name.

Comment: You need to explain what is happening currently with the above code. Are you not getting the expected result? Provide full information. Btw, welcome to StackOverFlow

Comment: No of course I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: this is not the way how it works. You need to explain what are you getting as a result, basically examples... :)

Comment: Okay i edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the `console.log` outside of the `fetch`, since you are using `.then` you should be aware that it's async.

Another issue on top of that is that you don't lowercase the search input

Also probably shouldn't fetch on every keyup, just get the country names outside and then look through.

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById("input");

fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const countries = data.Country;
        searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
            const search = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
            const suggestions = countries
                .filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search));
            console.log(suggestions)
        });
    });
```